# why inner join on condition does not use key

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table as

```
create table temp_test2 (
date_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date` date NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (date_id)
);

create table temp_test1 (
date_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date` date NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (date_id)
);


explain select * from temp_test as t  inner join temp_test2 as t2 on (t2.date_id =t.date_id) limit 3;

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | date_id       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ALL  | date_id       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

why the `code_id` key is not used in both the table, but when I use `code_id=something` in on condition it's using the key,

```
explain select * from temp_test as t  inner join temp_test2 as t2 on (t2.date_id =t.date_id and t.date_id =1) limit 3;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                       | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | const | PRIMARY,date_id,date_id_2,date_id_3 | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref   | date_id,date_id_2,date_id_3         | date_id | 4       | const |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

I tried (unique,composite primary,composite) key also but it is not working.
Can anyone explain why this so?

Comment: It could depend on the amount of rows in your table, or also the version of MySQL. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Because your tables contain a very small number of records, the optimiser decides that it is not worth using the index. A table scan will do just as good.

Also, you selected all fields (`SELECT *`), if it used the index for executing the `JOIN` a row scan would still be required to get the full contents.

The query would be more likely to use the index if:

- you selected only the `date_id` field
- there were more than 4 rows in `temp_test`

Comment: Hi,my actual tables records will be more then 1 billion,while joining billion records , primary key(date_id,day) not working,its selecting all table range

Comment: @user2728070 Sorry, I may be misunderstanding: are you actually getting the same execution plan with a table with 1 billion records?

Comment: Here the explain statement of my table *************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: t
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,child_cdepth_parent,child_code_key,child_depth
          key: child_depth
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 19156
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 4. row ***************************composite primary key (child_code_id,child_depth),I am using child_code_id in on condition (i.e) on (code_id=child_code_id) and child_depth =0

Comment: @user2728070 It says "key: child_depth". This query does use the `child_depth` index.

Comment: you are right it is using child_depth key,but my question is why it is not using composite primary key(child_code_id,child_depth)

Comment: Please show the full table description (with indexes) as well as your query. You might want to edit your question.

Comment: But since the primary key index **is** the actual table, isn't using the primary key identical to doing a table scan for very small tables? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: The optimizer may not bother checking whether the primary key covers all columns. In most cases indeed, `SELECT *` will lead to a table row read. And in such a contrieved example, I think we are splitting hairs. There is absolutely no significant difference between scanning the table or to the index, in a table with 4 rows.